# Rails 4 production env not finding fonts in app/assets/fonts/?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fonts

I'm using Rails 4 and trying to deploy to production, but my fonts are not loading properly. I have all my fonts in my `app/assets/fonts` folder. When I go on the homepage and look at the browser console, I see this:

```
    "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://staging.mysite.com/assets/sourcesanspro-regular-webfont.woff"
    sources...nt.woff
    "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://staging.mysite.com/assets/OpenSans-CondLight-webfont.woff"
    OpenSan...nt.woff
    "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://staging.mysite.com/assets/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.0.3"
    fontawe...v=4.0.3
    "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://staging.mysite.com/assets/sourcesanspro-regular-webfont.ttf"
    sources...ont.ttf
    "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://staging.mysite.com/assets/OpenSans-CondLight-webfont.ttf"
    OpenSan...ont.ttf
    "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://staging.mysite.com/assets/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.0.3"
    fontawe...v=4.0.3
```

My project directory looks like this in `app/assets`:

```
    .
    ├── fonts
    │   ├── DroidSans-webfont.eot
    │   ├── DroidSans-webfont.svg
    │   ├── DroidSans-webfont.ttf
    │   ├── DroidSans-webfont.woff
    │   ├── FontAwesome.otf
    │   ├── OpenSans-CondLight-webfont.eot
    │   ├── OpenSans-CondLight-webfont.svg
    │   ├── OpenSans-CondLight-webfont.ttf
    │   ├── OpenSans-CondLight-webfont.woff
    │   ├── fontawesome-webfont.eot
    │   ├── fontawesome-webfont.svg
    │   ├── fontawesome-webfont.ttf
    │   ├── fontawesome-webfont.woff
    │   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
    │   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
    │   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
    │   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
    │   ├── sourcesanspro-regular-webfont.eot
    │   ├── sourcesanspro-regular-webfont.svg
    │   ├── sourcesanspro-regular-webfont.ttf
    │   └── sourcesanspro-regular-webfont.woff
    └── stylesheets
        ├── admin.css
        ├── application.css.scss
        ├── bootstrap.css
        ├── font-awesome.min.css
        ├── jquery.bxslider.css
        ├── smoothproducts.css
        └── style.css.scss
```

in my `application.css.scss`, I have this:

```
     *
     *= require_tree .
     *= require_self
     */
    @import 'style';
```

and in my `style.css.scss` I have this:

```
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'open_sanscondensed_light';
        src: url('OpenSans-CondLight-webfont.eot');
        src: url('OpenSans-CondLight-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
             url('OpenSans-CondLight-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
             url('OpenSans-CondLight-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
             url('OpenSans-CondLight-webfont.svg#open_sanscondensed_light') format('svg');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'source_sans_proregular';
        src: url('sourcesanspro-regular-webfont.eot');
        src: url('sourcesanspro-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
             url('sourcesanspro-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
             url('sourcesanspro-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
             url('sourcesanspro-regular-webfont.svg#source_sans_proregular') format('svg');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'DroidSansRegular';
        src: url('DroidSans-webfont.eot');
        src: url('DroidSans-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
             url('DroidSans-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
             url('DroidSans-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
             url('DroidSans-webfont.svg#DroidSansRegular') format('svg');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
```

Could someone please help!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Rails production you need to precompile your assets, which will cause rails to add a fingerprint the each file and put them into the assets folder.

The issue you're having if you've done this, is because you're using the the standard css url in your stylesheets, and that file does not exist in production.

What you need to do if make a few alterations. Firstly, edit your `config/environments/production.rb` to include the fonts in the pre-compilation stage

```
config.assets.precompile << /\.(?:svg|eot|woff|ttf)\z/
```

Then precompile your assets

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```

Then inside the stylesheet, rails provides font specific URL helpers, so you can do

```
src: url(font-path('myfont-webfont.eot'))
```

Comment: Do I need to change my css file to sass or anything to get the `font-path` helper?

Comment: You're already using the .scss extension so it should already be available for you to use :)

Comment: hey! @PaRee it seems to have worked for most of them, except for 2.. the ones with the MD hash at the end. I'll update my question with details

Comment: never mind i think i know!! these fonts are being included in another stylesheet, I forgot to update that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Read about [Rails Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).

Precompile your assets in the 'production' environment

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:clean assets:precompile
```

In your CSS, use `asset_path` helper. Like this:

Instead of

```
src: url('sourcesanspro-regular-webfont.eot');
```

use

```
src: url(font-path('sourcesanspro-regular-webfont.eot'));
```

Making this change will add MD5 hashes to your font url. For this to work, you need to include your font's extension (ttf, eot etc) to `config.assets.precompile` in your configuration file.